# Post-processing individual MSAA samples in CPU

Tags: opengl, msaa

I'm interested in sub-pixel sampling my OpenGL renders around the edge silhouettes of my meshes for a computer vision task. I'm thinking of using MSAA to do it efficiently (but the application is not for anti-aliasing). The problem I find with multisampling is that in order to read the samples from the GPU I can only blit the framebuffers into a non multisampling one, thus I cannot recover individual sample information. My questions are:

- Is there a way to impelement a fragment shader that stores the results of a per-sample (GL_SAMPLE_SHADING) computation such that I can read those samples back to CPU? I've thought of using glSampleID to index the output to different out buffers but don't know if that's possible at all. Perhaps a method  like the linked-list structures used for OIT (i.e. http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2014/presentations/S4385-order-independent-transparency-opengl.pdf)? However, there they perform all computations on GPU so I'm not sure if I can read the linked list data from the CPU in any way.

Maybe MSAA is the wrong approach and there are other methods to do so. I guess my last resort is to super sample the render x times and thus recover individual samples, but that seems to be a very inefficient solution.

Comment: Are you rendering to a multi sampled framebuffer? If yes you can get individual samples with `texelfetch()`.

Comment: Ah I missed texefetch, looks like a useful method. If I understand correctly then, I'd have to: Store on the first pass all the results of my shader computations on a multisampled texture (via imageStore?).  Then,  run a shader N  times (where N is number of samples used) that simply retrieves the image samples using texelfetch?

Comment: You can render to it the same way as to normal textures. A for retrieving you can make a loop over all samples in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a compute shader which reads the samples and writes each sample's data via [`imageLoad`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store), and then writes it to an [SSBOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) (FS outputs and [image load/store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) would not be appropriate for the output). You'll need the usual memory barrier synchronization when it comes time to read it, but this way, you can write directly to a [buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object), rather than having to use a [PBO to read from a texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object).

The hardest part will be converting `gl_GlobalInvocationID` and the other compute shader inputs into the index in the SSBO array as well as the texture coordinate and sample index for your `imageLoad` operation.